# My score is visible but like score +13 , but actual number does not increase.

Tags: bug, reputation

I got 10 more scores in StackOverflow but it does not reflect in the scoreboard. please help me 
[image]

[image]

Comment: why do you say it doesn't reflect in the chart?  You have 213, the chart shows 213.  Looks like everything is correct

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing any reputation.

Try hovering over the +10, and you'll see this:

> [image]
>   +10 Reputation gained since your last visit to the reputation tab

Similar to your inbox, this total is just a counter of how much rep you have accumulated since you last checked. Checking the reputation tab in your profile will reset the counter.